# How to change text from Android ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I click on item 0(Bacon) then app close.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ListView buckyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.buckyListView);
        String[] foods = {"Bacon", "Tuna", "Ham", "Bucky", "Tommy", "Sunny", "Mommy", "Burger", "Pizza", "HotDog", "Muniraka", "Mouse", "Keyboard", "Tenda", "Iron", "Public", "Life", "Good", "Keyboard", "PenDrive", "RedFort"};

        ListAdapter buckysAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foods);

        buckyListView.setAdapter(buckysAdapter);

        buckyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch(position) {
                    case 0:
                        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        tv.setText("TextView was Clicked");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How to change text when i click on item? I am using latest version of android studio and I have to build this project on API 15.

```
08-03 10:35:46.037 707-997/? E/MountService: Failed to read response to volume shared /storage/emulated/0 ums
08-03 10:35:46.203 707-3517/? E/MountService: Failed to read response to volume shared /storage/emulated/0 ums
08-03 10:35:46.339 707-997/? E/MountService: mount service registerListener=android.os.storage.IMountServiceListener$Stub$Proxy@42f00498
08-03 10:35:46.339 707-853/? E/MountService: Failed to read response to volume shared /storage/emulated/0 ums
08-03 10:37:34.868 707-717/? E/Sensors: new acc setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000) err! go to hwmsen
08-03 10:38:37.970 7618-7618/? E/dalvikvm: /system/framework/mediatek-op.jar odex has stale dependencies
08-03 10:38:38.000 7618-7618/? E/dalvikvm: /system/framework/am.jar odex has stale dependencies
08-03 10:38:38.004 7618-7618/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-03 10:38:38.174 7618-7618/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-03 10:38:38.174 7618-7618/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-03 10:38:38.411 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.412 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.412 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.412 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.414 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.416 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.416 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.418 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.423 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.425 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:38.427 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity.access$super
08-03 10:38:54.435 7634-7634/com.example.android.bucky45 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.android.bucky45, PID: 7634
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 10:41:35.160 707-717/? E/Sensors: new acc setDelay handle(0),ns(20000000) err! go to hwmsen
08-03 10:41:57.947 7720-7720/? E/lcdc_cap: [DDMSCap]pmem_alloc size = 0x00384020, addr = 0xb6ad8008
08-03 10:43:28.480 7729-7729/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.gsa.assist.GsaVoiceInteractionSession', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.assist.GsaVoiceInteractionSession_MembersInjector.au
08-03 10:43:28.499 7729-7729/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.gsa.tasks.VelvetBackgroundTasksJobService', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.tasks.l.au
08-03 10:43:28.522 945-1860/? E/ctxmgr: [AppIntervalImpl]closeInterval: ongoing
08-03 10:43:28.726 7729-7750/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.content.pm.LauncherApps', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.shared.multiuser.l.connect
08-03 10:43:29.234 7729-7729/? E/CardSyncManagerImpl: onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
08-03 10:43:29.234 7729-7760/? E/CardSyncManagerImpl: Failed to connect to GoogleApiClient: null
08-03 10:43:29.416 7729-7763/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.content.pm.LauncherApps', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.s.a.a.n
08-03 10:43:29.587 7729-7729/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.chromium.net.s', referenced from method org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.<init>
08-03 10:43:30.616 7729-7764/? E/GeofenceHelper: Failed: remove geofences by PendingIntent
```

This layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   

 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.android.bucky45.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buckyListView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="147dp"></ListView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />
```

check this code and please correct this It is really very Important

Comment: Post the logcat output please.

Comment: Are you sure it can find the TextView and tv is not NULL here: TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

Comment: Please add layout xml

Comment: You'r using `ArrayAdapter<String>` so of course you need to use `TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.textView1);` or you can make custom adapter class in which you can inflate your custom layout with textview.

Comment: use TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent); instead of your code for declaring textview this will help you

Comment: posted the xml checkout

Comment: where I use this code TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

Answer (score 0):

I would just implement a custom adapter

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ListView buckyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.buckyListView);
        String[]  foods = {"Bacon", "Tuna", "Ham", "Bucky", "Tommy", "Sunny", "Mommy", "Burger", "Pizza", "HotDog", "Muniraka", "Mouse", "Keyboard", "Tenda", "Iron", "Public", "Life", "Good", "Keyboard", "PenDrive", "RedFort"};
        CustomAdapter buckysAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arrays.asList(foods));

        buckyListView.setAdapter(buckysAdapter);

        buckyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
                adapter.updateItem(position, "New String");
            }
        });

    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        List<String> mStrings;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> strings) {
            super(context, resource);
            mStrings = strings;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mStrings.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mStrings.get(position);
        }

        public void updateItem(int index, String string) {
            mStrings.set(index, string);
            //To redraw we must notify the list the underlying data has changed
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on this snippet :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
ListView buckyListView;
ArrayAdapter<String> buckysAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buckyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.buckyListView);

    String[]  foods = {"Bacon", "Tuna", "Ham", "Bucky", "Tommy", "Sunny", "Mommy", "Burger", "Pizza", "HotDog", "Muniraka", "Mouse", "Keyboard", "Tenda", "Iron", "Public", "Life", "Good", "Keyboard", "PenDrive", "RedFort"};
    buckysAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foods);
    buckyListView.setAdapter(buckysAdapter);

    buckyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    tv.setText("TextView was Clicked");
                    break;
                default:

                    break;
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: pls post your logcat :)

Comment: checkout now I have posted

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1.If you use **default** adapter such as:

```
 adapterSub = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mStringListSub);
```

then you can access to the **TextView** by this:

```
listViewSub.setOnItemClickListener((parent, viewSub, positionSub, idSub) -> {
                TextView tv = (TextView) viewSub;
```

2.If you use **Custom adapter** by your Layout such as :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.special_row, R.id.tv_sp_row, mStringList);
```

then you can follow this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
                -> {
            TextView tvS= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sp_row);
```